# How can I transplant sprouts growing from a Mimosa stump?

Tags: trees, planting, transplanting, propagation

I cut down a mimosa tree and now there are tiny sprouts coming out of the stump. Is there any way I can transfer and plant the tiny trees somewhere else?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you please [edit] a picture or two into your post. That way we can see your exact tree and what those sprouts look like. Also, where do you live? How old and how tall are those sprouts? We need as many details as possible in order to give you the best answers. Since you're new here, check out our [help] to learn how the site works. [Ask] is a good place to start and will explain why we're asking all these questions!  We look forward to helping you and hope you enjoy being here.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you mean Albizia julbrissin or Acacia dealbata when you say Mimosa tree? If the former, was it a special variety, such as chocolate mimosa?

Answer (score 3):

If the sprouts are growing from the stem/roots beneath the surface, they will root into the soil and can be detached at the base, and transferred to a new location. Do this while the plant is dormant, or it could die from over transpiration.

If the sprouts are growing from the stump above the soil line, heap lightweight growing medium (like soilless potting mix) over the stump at least 6" up the stems of the sprouts. Keep this moist throughout the season. When the plant goes dormant, check for roots. If there are only a few, wait another season. The next year, check again. If you have strong roots in the mound, congratulations! You've successfully mound layered your new trees! They can be detached at the base and moved on.